# How to count numpy array elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy Array name 
`odd_num_mul = [ 2  0  0  0  0 12  0  8]`
I want to count the numbers of elements in this array.For ex - (8 elements in this case). How can I count?

Comment: Add a python tag please

Comment: Also, that's a list, not an array

Comment: Did you try ``len``, like for all Python containers?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is my code- odd_num_ary = np.array([odd_num], dtype= np.int32)
odd_num_mul = odd_num_ary*2   print(odd_num_mul)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `arr.size` or `np.prod(arr.shape)`

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8]
nParr = np.array(arr)
nParr.size
```